# Accessing values from a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mysqli

In my PHP application, I need to take a multidimensional array and extract values in a for loop. The query will always return 9 rows.

```
$w = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT age, percent FROM drive03_2_monthly_income WHERE birthYear='1956' AND (age LIKE '%.00%') ORDER BY birthYear,age ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($w);
    for($n=0;$n<9;$n++) {
        echo $row[$n]->age." -- ".$row[$n]->percent."<br />";
        }
```

When I run this, I get the data I want in $w, but having a problem extracting values in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

here you are.

```
<?php
$w = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT age, percent FROM drive03_2_monthly_income WHERE birthYear='1956' AND (age LIKE '%.00%') ORDER BY birthYear,age ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($w, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{ 
     echo $row['age']->age." -- ".$row['percent']->percent."<br />";  
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) gets a single row. You have a few options for next steps.

Option 1 - Use `mysqli_fetch_array()` in a loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($w)){
    // Do something with your associative row data
    echo $row['age'];
}
```

Option 2 - Use [`mysqli_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) in a loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($w)){
    // Do something with your object row data
    echo $row->name;
}
```

Option 3 - Use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

```
foreach(mysqli_fetch_all($w, MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row){ 
    // Do something with your associative row data
    echo $row['age'];
}
```

This is not recommended, as quoted on the documentation.

> As mysqli_fetch_all() returns all the rows as an array in a single
>   step, it may consume more memory than some similar functions such as
>   mysqli_fetch_array(), which only returns one row at a time from the
>   result set. Further, if you need to iterate over the result set, you
>   will need a looping construct that will further impact performance.
>   For these reasons mysqli_fetch_all() should only be used in those
>   situations where the fetched result set will be sent to another layer
>   for processing.